# Nest js Circular Dependency & Mongoose Model imports

Tags: nestjs, circular-dependency, mongoose-models

```
    @Injectable()
     export class ItemService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Item.name) private itemModel: Model<ItemDocument>,
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => KitchenService)) private KitchenService: kitchenService,
  ) { }

  async getItems() {
    const items: IItem[] = await this.itemModel.aggregate([
      .......
    ]);
    return items;
  }
}
```

In this, I can't able to use the itemModel. I'm getting an error like

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'aggregate')
at ItemService.getItemsForCaching (/Users/dhodrajsundaram/Desktop/Work Space/cookr-menu-service/src/item/item.service.ts:151:55)
at /Users/dhodrajsundaram/Desktop/Work Space/cookr-menu-service/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:38:29
at InterceptorsConsumer.intercept (/Users/dhodrajsundaram/Desktop/Work Space/cookr-menu-service/node_modules/@nestjs/core/interceptors/interceptors-consumer.js:11:20)
at /Users/dhodrajsundaram/Desktop/Work Space/cookr-menu-service/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:60
at /Users/dhodrajsundaram/Desktop/Work Space/cookr-menu-service/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:23
at /Users/dhodrajsundaram/Desktop/Work Space/cookr-menu-service/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-explorer.js:177:162
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)